# Spring Boot and RxJava2 Integration - NullPointerException: Actually not

Tags: rx-java2

Attempting to invoke RxJava2 from Spring Boot ApplicationRunner, I get a very cryptic exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:770)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:757)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.silanis.ps.dtool.Application.main(Application.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Actually not, but can't throw other exceptions due to RS
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12995)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12932)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip$ZipCoordinator.subscribe(FlowableZip.java:127)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableZip.subscribeActual(FlowableZip.java:79)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(FlowableDoOnEach.java:49)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableTake.subscribeActual(FlowableTake.java:32)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableDoOnEach.subscribeActual(FlowableDoOnEach.java:49)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFlatMapSingle.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMapSingle.java:54)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12935)
    at com.silanis.ps.dtool.services.CliRunner.run(CliRunner.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:767)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:565)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.schedulePeriodicallyDirect(NewThreadWorker.java:91)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ComputationScheduler.schedulePeriodicallyDirect(ComputationScheduler.java:139)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableInterval.subscribeActual(FlowableInterval.java:46)
    at io.reactivex.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:12986)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

What does `java.lang.NullPointerException: Actually not, but can't throw other exceptions due to RS` actually mean?

Something that has to do with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:565)
at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.NewThreadWorker.schedulePeriodicallyDirect(NewThreadWorker.java:91)
```

ANSWER:

As mentionned in the comments on this issue, this error is thrown when a `Flowable.interval` is initialized with a value of `0`. Setting the value to a positive value solved the issue.

Comment: This is one of my favorite error messages :) It indicates a bug in an operator that prompts investigation. Indeed as @Kiskae mentioned, having non-positive period is not handled (or disallowed). In theory, it could indicate an immediate rescheduling but usually such very high frequency execution is not what the developer wants. It would be great if you could figure out why you have a period of zero or less.

Comment: @akarnokd I will keep investigating... could it be related to the fact that the `ApplicationRunner` `run` method executes in a certain thread different from the rxjava code? My oversimplified test seem to indicate that the run method completes sooner than the rxjava code and most likely Spring Boot closes the jvm. Could this cause this kind of exception from occurring? If so, I will need to look how to hook Spring thread with rxjava `observeOn` or `subscribeOn` (I am not yet quite familiar on how to use those...). Thanks for your help and let me know what you think.

Comment: I doubt Spring uses Flowable.interval for anything so there should be something in your code that ends up with 0 or negative as a period, perhaps a missing or wrong configuration that the dependency injection misses.

Comment: @akarnokd and @Kiskae, you are correct, after inspection of my code, I found that my `Flowable.interval` was initialized with a value of `0` due to an error initializing my configuration object using dependency injection. Looks like the issue is solved. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null`

It is not a very helpful exception but it seems that exception occurs when `period <= 0` according to the source code.

Since you simplified your code it is not clear where that value might occur, but it seems this error happens when the period provided to `Flowable.interval` is 0 or negative. For some reason RxJava accepts a period of `0` which the ThreadPoolExecutor does not accept.

EDIT: When RxJava 2.1.1 releases this bug will be fixed and result in immediate rescheduling of the runnable if `period <= 0`.